# Inheritance of inherited abstract class with realization

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract

sorry i don't know how to write my problem in couple words, so i couldn't even properly google it.

thing is: i have chain of abstract classes.

```
 AbEntity with abstract properties.

    AbHero and AbEnemy with realization of AbEntity's properties and with it's own abstract properties

        Non-abstract classes.
```

For some reason non-abstract classes should have their realization of AbEntity's abstract properties. Why can't they take it from parents (AbHero & AbEnemy)?

I don't understand how to make this architecture without abstract classes, but i don't want to write 7 extraproperties with return base.PropName; in every non-abstract class :(

Interface wont work because i need to use fields. (it's unity)

Comment: Please show example code.

Comment: Just make the properties in the abstract classes non-abstract. "abstract" means "Must be implemented by concrete sub-classes", which is not what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can still use virtual properties and override it when you need to.

Comment: 1. Any non-abstract class should have all members implemented
2. Any abstract class can have abstract members (properties / methods without bodies)
3. When you implementing non-abstract child of abstract parent - you should implement all abstract members.

Looks like when you implementing Non-abstract classes, you forget to implement some of abstract properties. What's your classes exactly? What error message do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason non-abstract classes should have their realization of AbEntity's abstract properties.

That's not true, if they inherit of abHero and abHero already implements the abstract AbEntity properties then there's no need to implement them again, look at this example:

```
public abstract class a
{
    public abstract int value{ get; }
}

public abstract class b : a
{
    public abstract int valueb { get; }
    public override int value
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}

public class c : b
{
    public override int valueb
    {
        get { return 2; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the scheme. Thanks. Reboot saved me)

Answer (score 0):

Your questions isn't clear, so I just show you how declare a 3-level hierarchy.

1. A abstract base class with one abstract property:

   ```
   abstract class AbEntity
   {
       public abstract int PropertyEntity { get; }
   }
   ```
2. A derived still abstract class with an implementation of `PropertyEntity` and another abstract property added.

   ```
   abstract class AbHero : AbEntity
   {
       public override int PropertyEntity { get { /* ... */ } }

       public abstract string PropertyHero { get; }
   }
   ```
3. A non derived class implementing the remaining abstract properties (just `PropertyHero`, not `PropertyEntity`)

   ```
   class NonAbstractHero : AbHero
   {
       public override string PropertyHero { get { /* ... */ } }
   }
   ```